# woocommerce - Get Cart Total as number

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get total price of cart in my woocommerce plugin.

I want to get it as a float number like so: 21.00 but I don't know how to get it. My code outputs weird results, this is my exact code:

```
$total         = $woocommerce->cart->get_total();
$total_a       = WC()->cart->get_total();
$total1        = $woocommerce->cart->get_total_ex_tax();
$total1_a      = WC()->cart->get_total_ex_tax();
$total2        = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
$total2_a      = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
```

outputs:

```
0,00 €
0,00 €
0,00 €
0,00 €
21,00 €
21,00 €
```

and if I convert from string to float the result is of course 0.00.

Any help how to get cart total in the form of float number ?

Comment: Look in the cart class. [`get_total()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1959) method formats the price using `wc_price()`. So, as @José has pointed out you just need to access the public property.

Answer (score 18):

I have code like this and working perfect:

```
if ( ! WC()->cart->prices_include_tax ) {
    $amount = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
} else {
    $amount = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total + WC()->cart->tax_total;
}
```

good luck !

Comment: This way doesn't include shipping price.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? When prices include taxes no taxes should be added.

Comment: This code still works on WooCommerce versions 5.4.x

Answer (score 12):

Just access the `total` property directly, it's public:

```
global $woocommerce;
echo $woocommerce->cart->total;
```

Comment: it seem not working with woocommerce version 2.6.x or higher . do you have another way ?

Comment: its working Thank you mate!

Answer (score 4):

```
global $woocommerce;
$amount = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total+$woocommerce->cart->tax_total;
```

You can also convert $amount in float value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total (Cart total)
$woocommerce->cart->tax_total (tax total)
$woocommerce->cart->shipping_total (shipping total)
```

Comment: Please describe your answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
WC()->cart->cart_contents_total

Answer (score 2):

In 2020 with Woocommerce 4+

```
$total_cart = WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal(); // without taxs and shipping fees
echo $total_cart; // ex: 0.00
```

Comment: Thank you, finally something working in 2020 ... I cant' believe it's almost impossible to get cart total amount as float / int in WooCommerce.

Comment: Strange but it is true, although: `WC()->cart->total` still works for me, but getting this value without a getter worries me a little.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use `get_total()` while passing in a context other than the default of 'view'. When the context is view, the price will be formatted for display. When set to anything else, it'll pass back the raw value.

Example:

```
WC()->cart->get_total( 'raw' );
```

---

It's also worth noting that `$woocommerce` (providing you've accessed the global first of course) is exactly the same as `WC()`. I'd recommend preferring `WC()` whereever possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are methods for it, you don't need to get them from a property.

Use: `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total()`

Instead of: `WC()->cart->cart_contents_total`

---

And use: `WC()->cart->get_taxes_total()`

Instead of: `WC()->cart->tax_total`

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce 4.8 `WC()->cart->total` works fine, although it worries me a little getting this value without a help of a getter but it seems to be the easiest method right now.