# Get the cart totals non formatted values as float numbers in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, properties, woocommerce, cart

How can I get the cart total/total_ex_tax **as** float **number**?

I looked for, but all answers are like:

a) Ugly usage reg_exp (For example, what if we will be to use ',' instead '.'?):

```
global $woocommerce;
$amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
```

b) Direct access to class properties (which can be to change in future; and not the OOP method). It works, but it's a wrong way:

```
global $woocommerce;
echo $woocommerce->subtotal;
echo $woocommerce->subtotal_ex_tax;
echo $woocommerce->total;
echo $woocommerce->total_ex_tax;
echo $woocommerce->cart_contents_total;
```

I want to get normal API something like this:

```
$wc = WC();
echo $wc->cart->get_total_as_number();
echo $wc->cart->get_total_ex_tax_as_number();
```

Comment: [woocommerce - Get Cart Total as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063173/woocommerce-get-cart-total-as-number) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `WC()->cart` (the `WC_Cart` class object) you can use methods or access properties listed on the following [`WC_Cart` class documentation Api](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html).

So with `WC()->cart` you can access the **properties directly** and get **non formatted values** using:

```
echo WC()->cart->subtotal;
echo WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;
echo WC()->cart->total;
echo WC()->cart->total_ex_tax;
echo WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
```

You will get **float numbers** for all. Remember that `WC()->cart` is a live object.

> `WC()->cart` replace totally `global $woocommerce;` with `$woocommerce->cart`, so no need to use outdated `global $woocommerce;` with it…

---

Related official documentation: [`WC_Cart` class api, methods and properties](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)

Comment: Looks like you are right. I used it. But what about OOP & encapsulation & setters/getters?..